# reveal.js title slide override

Tags: javascript, html, css, reveal.js

I would like to style my reveal.js very first (title) slide slightly differently than my other slides.
How could I create a separate section environment for "title" slides with:

1. All headings and text centered?
2. All contents vertically aligned in the middle?

My default (content) slides should be left-aligned and not vertically centered. This means that in the init part `Reveal.initialize({... center: false, ...})`

And for my custom *theme.css*, all headings and paragraph text are left-aligned with `text-align: left`.

I was hoping there would be some `<section data-center=true>` override option, but there does not seem to be. I have been fiddling with div's, but I am no great HTML/CSS guru.

As a follow up question, could this be automatically triggered if `<h1>` is used on a slide? That would allow me to use external Markdown for the contents and nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a class to namespace your title slide

```
<section class="title-slide">
    <h1>Title</h1>
</section>
```

and style it with a higher specificity than the other slides

```
h1 {
    text-align: left;
}

.title-slide h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

This should address your second question as well without having to trigger anything dynamically.

Comment: Thank you! Quite new to this still... How would I override the vertical positioning done by Reveal.config?

Comment: Ah, I found the centering too. Alignment is a hassle sometimes... 
`.reveal .title-slide {
    top: 50%; 
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%); 
    position: absolute;
}`

and your solution did the trick.

Comment: Hi chazsolo, perhaps you would happen to know this too. Part 2 isn't actually completely solved. Using this specific vertical alignment breaks various Reveal.JS elements like the slide overview (ESC button) and the regular transitions (you can see the vertical translation in motion).

Do you know of other ways to center these specific slides in Reveal.JS without centering all of them?

Comment: I would take a look at flexbox; [here's a useful guide I refer to often](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox).